# In Hibernate what is Method chaining?

Tags: hibernate

In a Hibernate context what is meant by Method chaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing that is meant in other contexts.

`thing.meth1().meth2().meth3()....`

Note that `meth` has to return something that has the method `meth2`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Method chaining is a programming style supported by many Hibernate interfaces (see @hvgotcodes example). If you do use this coding style, it’s better to write each method invocation on a different line.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
.addResource("test.hbm.xml")
.buildSessionFactory();
```

Otherwise, it may be difficult to step through the code in your debugger.